# HTTPGet subject line

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using HTTPGet to generate a dynamic subject line which works fine when I use this code:

```
 %%=HTTPGet("http://sandbox.site.com/newsletters/daily_subject.php")=%%
```

But the following does not work. Actually, it works in the preview but not when the email is sent:

```
 %%before; httpget; 1 "http://sandbox.site.com/newsletters/daily_subject.php"%%
```

I would prefer to use the second because I only want to make one http request. Any ideas?

Comment: Where in Salesforce are you doing this?

Comment: Marketing Cloud / email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using HTTPGET() function in AMPScript, if the URL is static, it will cache the value so it won't be calling it uniquely for each subscriber.

Comment: How to you mean a static URL? Meaning the page that it directs you to is static? Or that no variables are passed in the URL?

Comment: No variables are passed in the URL.

Comment: We tested and it worked great. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to have `httpgetwrap` enabled by SFMC Support for your second scenario to work.

I believe they call it **WRAP HTTPGET URLS**.